# What is an elegant idiom for a lexicographic Ord instance?

Tags: haskell, lexicographic

This code works, but it's verbose, and I'm sure there's a more concise way.

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V

data Event a = Event { start :: Time
                     , duration :: Time
                     , payload :: Maybe a } deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Ord a => Ord (Event a) where
  (<=) a b = start a < start b
    || start a == start b && duration a < duration b
    || start a == start b && duration a == duration b && payload a <= payload b
```

The idea behind it is that if one thing starts before the other, you should call it the lesser, and don't even look at the other two fields. Similarly, if they start at the same time but one is more brief, then that briefer one is the lesser, and you can ignore the third field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @HTNW notes, the automatically derived `Ord` instance will work.  In more general situations, if you need to sort lexicographically on multiple items each with existing `Ord` instances, you can use the automatic tuple `Ord` instance:

```
instance Ord a => Ord (Event a) where
  (<=) a b = order a <= order b
    where order x = (start x, duration x, payload x)
```

Comment: If you want to save keystrokes, you can use `Data.Function.on`: ``(<=) = (<=) `on` order``. You can also make it a one (well, two)-liner: `(<=) = on (<=) $ (,,) <$> start <*> duration <*> payload`

Answer (score 6):

Use `deriving`:

```
data Event a = Event { start :: Time
                     , duration :: Time
                     , payload :: Maybe a } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

The derived instance is automatically lexicographic.

Answer (score 3):

[As HTNW suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48727871/2751851), use `deriving` if you can. If you can't (e.g. the record fields aren't in the appropriate order, or you aren't actually writing an instance), a very nice option is doing it in terms of `compare` (or [`comparing`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing), which adds extra convenience in your case) rather than `(<=)` and then taking advantage of the `Monoid` instance for `Ordering`, which amounts to lexicographic order:

```
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.Monoid ((<>))

instance Ord a => Ord (Event a) where
    compare a b = comparing start a b
        <> comparing duration a b
        <> comparing payload a b
```

As functions have a `Monoid` instance which acts on the results, you might take it even further:

```
instance Ord a => Ord (Event a) where
    compare = comparing start <> comparing duration <> comparing payload
```

Comment: Nice. Now I feel foolish for having written `applyCmp f x y = mconcat (f <*> pure x <*> pure y)` a week ago.